# MATLAB function that gives all the positive integers in a column vector

Tags: matlab

I need to create a function that has the input argument n, a integer , n>1 , and an output argument v, which is a column vector of length n containing all the positive integers smaller than or equal to n, arranged in such a way that no element of the vector equals its own index.
I know how to define the function
This is what I tried so far but it doesn't work

```
function[v]=int_col(n)
[1,n] = size(n);
k=1:n;
v=n(1:n);
v=k'
end
```

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: It is homework , I am following a matlab online course , but this is my first problem ever in matlab , and to be honest , it's pretty complicated for me (i'm 15) and I do not intend to copy every answer I find online.

Comment: I would recommend [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for your first attempt. I'd also recommend taking a step back, breaking your code into steps, and writing some [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) for each step in the process before you start trying to write the actual code.

Comment: Your first task is to figure out how to make an arbitrarily-sized vector with values 1-N where each element is not equal to its index. Don't overthink it, there's an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's give a working solution. You should really look into it and see how this thing works. It's important to solve the problem in smaller steps and to know what the code is doing.

```
function [v] = int_col(n)
    if n <= 1
        error('argument must be >1')
    end

    v = 1:n;                % generate a row-vector of 1 to n
    v = v';                 % make it a column vector
    v = circshift(v,1);     % shift all elements by 1 
end
```

*This is the result:*

```
>> int_col(5)
ans =
     5
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

---

Instead of using `circshift` you can do the following as well:

```
v = [v(end);v(1:end-1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what you have:

```
[1,n] = size(n);
```

This line doesn't make a lot of sense: `n` is an integer, which means that `size(n)` will give you `[1,1]`, you don't need that. (Also an expression like `[1,n]` can't be on the left hand side of an assignment.) Drop that line. It's useless.

```
k=1:n;
```

That line is pretty good, `k` is now a row vector of size `n` containing the integers from `1` to `n`.

```
v=n(1:n);
```

Doesn't make sense. `n` isn't a vector (or you can say it's a 1x1 vector) either way, indexing into it (that's what the parentheses do) doesn't make sense. Drop that line too.

```
v=k'
```

That's also a nice line. It makes a column vector `v` out of your row vector `k`. The only thing that this doesn't satisfy is the "arranged in such a way that no element of the vector equals its own index" part, since right now every element equals its own index. So now you need to find a way to either shift those elements or shuffle them around in some way that satisfies this condition and you'd be done.